# Off shift supervisor removed monitor from my cubicle

Tags: conflict

An off shift supervisor removed a monitor that I use daily with my laptop. I came into work one morning and it had just disappeared. Only the power cord and another cable remained. No note or email reason left. The bureau chief's secretary sent out a global email stating that a monitor had been removed from our floor. The off shift  supervisor had told his friend to hold it for him in his cubicle because it really  belonged someone else. My supervisor had given this monitor to me a few days earlier, saying it was new, and our desktop department said I could have it
.I am stuck in the middle of this mess. I think the real reason it was removed is because they off shift supervisor is upset with me about a different issue. Will he be punished?

Comment: I don't think any of us know whether or not this person will be punished, since we are just strangers on the internet.

Comment: Added info: The monitor has been returned to my cubicle. On the advice of others, I have secured it with a steel cable and padlock. They off shift supervisor has called out sick there past 2 workdays. He has shown poor judgement at times in the past. Got to love working for local government with union employees.

Comment: What do you mean by, "They off shift supervisor?" You used that twice now. Do you mean "The off shift supervisor?"

Comment: Just ask your manager to give you another monitor to work with. The monitor belongs to the company, if someone else took it away, it is not your problem. You focus on your own productivity, and forget about that off-shift supervisor. Whether he gets punished or not, and whether he has kept the monitor with a friend or an enemy has nothing to do with you. Don't go looking for trouble.

Comment: My smart phone likes to change "the" to "their" and "they", if I don't catch it, I make less sense, if that is possible?

Comment: I realize I don't own the tools at work, it just seems like I should not have to worry about a rouge supervisor,  who does not know the proper way to replace equipment. Taking and not replacing equipment in a cubicle with no notice or information afterward is not a productive way of doing business. My supervisor and I wasted half the morning playing detective. Was the monitor stolen? If not, where was it?

Comment: @Anonymous Certainly the off-shift supervisor's behaviour wasn't exemplary, but it is not your problem. You informed your supervisor that your monitor is missing, your responsibility ends there. If you and your supervisor wasting 4 hours each to look for the monitor is a concern, let your supervisor deal with it.

Answer (score 8):

Request a replacement monitor from your IT department.

If they point out that they already allocated one to you, point it that it was removed from your desk by persons unknown.

Let your supervisor sort things out.

Comment: Yep.  No confrontation required.  Report it missing and let them deal with it.